# How to check if two instances of the same java program are running?

Tags: java

Hi am making a program which will run through javaw.exe, so that it is not visible directly. Now my issue is sometime, (accidently) it can happen that the user runs multiple instances of the same application,

e.g entering `javaw myProgram` two times

Under such situation, is there any way i can prevent multiple instances of the same program to run if the program is already running.

Comment: this article explains multiple ways to prevent it:
http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0288.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Named/System mutex in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194227/named-system-mutex-in-java)

Comment: The socket technique there is a bit clumsy - you need a whole separate server process to prevent multiple instances. The `FileLock` technique is just plain wrong, because the `FileChannel.tryLock` method only checks for overlapping locks within one JVM, not across multiple JVMs. From the documentation of FileChannel.tryLock: "Throws OverlappingFileLockException - If a lock that overlaps the requested region is already held by this Java virtual machine"

Comment: @CameronSkinner thanks, are you sure that it doesnt return null in this case?

Comment: Also, from `java.nio.FileLock`: "Whether or not a lock actually prevents another program from accessing the content of the locked region is system-dependent and therefore unspecified"

Comment: @Scrum: Well, it *might* return null. But it's system dependent.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner, the FileLock technique is working fine (Win7, Java). Open 2 DosShell, you exec "java JustOneTest" in DosShell #1 and in DosShell #2, if you try to exec "java JustOneTest" the response is "Already active".

Comment: @RealHowTo: It's system dependent. What other operating systems have you tried?

Comment: @Cameron Skinner, Win7. In the HowTo, the lock file is tested with tryLock() which request an exclusive lock so the possibility that the OS permits shared lock is not a problem here.

Comment: @RealHowTo: Yes, but some operating/file systems do not support locks at all. That's the real problem; not shared locks. Maybe it's not an issue in this case but it's not something that can be relied upon.

Comment: @RealHowTo, Scrum: Huh. I was wrong. From the `File.createNewFile` documentation: "Note: this method should not be used for file-locking, as the resulting protocol cannot be made to work reliably. The FileLock facility should be used instead." I stand corrected.

Comment: This looks like an example of a 'good' dupe.  The answer may be the same but the way of asking is different enough that people probably won't find one when searching for the other.

Comment: @Cameron Skinner, if the OP considers it's problem (what OS do not support lock on file ?) then the socket technique is the way to go even if you see it as clumsy solution :-)

Comment: @Cameron the fact that it is "system-dependent", is that only regarding shared locks(in that case it will get converted to a exclusive)? but it will still return `null`?

Comment: @Scrum: It's system dependent in that not all operating/file systems support locking at all. Most do, but you need to check. Notably, networked file systems (like NFS) may not work as you would expect.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23620296)

Answer (score 1):

Although file lock is probably the simplest and easiest option, I'd like to mention one alternative: [JIntellitype](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/index.html) is a library which works only on Windows and has the [utility method](http://melloware.com/products/jintellitype/faq.html#two-instances) to check if the application window with the given title is already running.

If it just so happens that you're OK with having this functionality only on Windows and using file lock doesn't work for you... :)

Comment: Thanks for the props on Jintellitype.  While it is Windows only it uses the Windows API to guarantee two instances are not running.