# A way to check if a user is running a script?

Tags: java, sql, authentication, cron

Background info: Java script for a bot for a game, user runs a loader, enters their username and auth code, and the loader uses URLClassLoader to create an instance of the script to provide for the bot.

What I am trying to do: I wish to make it so that the user may only run 1 instance of the script at a time, and I am having trouble figuring out how exactly to do this.

How I theorized the process:
1. User enters info, info is checked, if so script will begin
2. In the sql table: add a column for authInUse and set value to 1 on script start
3. Every 10 minutes, ensure that authInUse is set to 1. Also in another column, lastUpdated value will contain timestamp.

The problem is how I'm going to set the authInUse to 0(false). I was thinking about having an SQL automated job(haven't researched much about them) to check if the auth is indeed in use, and if so, it will check the timestamp and if the timestamp was more than 10 minutes ago it will set the authInUse to false.

Is there any better or more reliable way to do this and am I overthinking it or is this how it is supposed to be done?

Comment: Read this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4495757/how-to-check-if-two-instances-of-the-same-java-program-are-running

Comment: Those are local solutions - I'm attempting to make this auth only usable by one person across IP addresses. Thanks though.