# How to synchronize access to a folder using java?

Tags: java, multithreading

The situation is as follows in my application I have 2 threads that run parallely, the purpose of one of the threads is to capture screenshots and the purpose of the second thread is to rename the screenshots that have been saved in a specific folder by the first thread - the code for the application is as follows -:

***CapturingAndRenamingSimultaneously.java***

```
/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: AnkitSablok
 * Date: 15/1/13
 * Time: 1:03 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

package com.tian.screenshotcapture;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class CapturingAndRenamingSimultaneously {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // we use the linked blocking queue here to resolve the concurrency issues
        final BlockingQueue<File> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<File>(1024);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                try {
                    System.out.println("In the capture thread now");
                    CaptureScreenshots.captureScreenshots(queue);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void run() {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        System.out.println("In the rename thread now");
                        RenameScreenShots.renameScreenshots(queue);
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

***CaptureScreenshots.java***

```
/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: AnkitSablok
 * Date: 15/1/13
 * Time: 12:35 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

// this code is used to capture the screenshots

package com.tian.screenshotcapture;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;

public class CaptureScreenshots {

    // this code is used to capture the screen shots
    public static void captureScreenshots(BlockingQueue<File> queue) throws Exception {

        String fileName = "C:\\Users\\ankitsablok\\Desktop\\Screenshots";
        int index = 0;

        for (; ; ) {
            ++index;
            Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Rectangle screenRectangle = new Rectangle(screenSize);
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRectangle);
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new File(fileName + "\\i" + index + ".jpg"));
            queue.put(new File(fileName + "\\i" + index + ".jpg"));

            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

***RenameScreenShots.java***

```
/**
 * Created with IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: AnkitSablok
 * Date: 15/1/13
 * Time: 12:49 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */

package com.tian.screenshotcapture;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class RenameScreenShots {
    public static void renameScreenshots(BlockingQueue<File> queue) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (int i = 0; i < queue.size(); ++i) {

            File sourceFile = queue.take();
            System.out.println("The filename is : " + sourceFile.getName());

            if (sourceFile.getName().contains("sent")) {
            } else {
                System.out.println("The modified name of the source file is :" + sourceFile.getName().substring(0,
                        sourceFile.getName().indexOf('.'))
                        + "sent" + ".jpg");

                File newFile = new File(sourceFile.getParent() + "/" + sourceFile.getName().substring(0,
                        sourceFile.getName().indexOf('.'))
                        + "sent" + ".jpg");

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newFile);

                int length;

                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }

                System.out.println("The file was deleted successfully : " + sourceFile.delete());

                fis.close();
                fos.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I want the access to the folder to be synchronized that is when one process writes the images to the folder after that the other process should be able to rename the images in the folder. But I am not able to synchronize access to the folder in which the screenshots are written and read, at some point of time using the above code gives a FileNotFoundException with the error that some other process is using the file. How can I resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a shared queue between two threads `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

From the thread `CaptureScreenshots` put into this queue the newly created `File` objects.

From the thread `RenameScreenShots` sequentially read from this queue prepared `File` objects and process them.

**UPD:** If you are afraid of that billions of image file will eat a lot of memory by their `File` descriptor, you can apply such an algorithm enhancing:

1. Create subfolders in a folder, which contains your image files and put image files into this subfolders.
2. Name those subfolders with integer names: `1`, `2`, `3`, ... , `89`.
3. Artificially limit number of files in each subfolder. When the number of files reaches the limit, just increase the name-number of the subfolder, create a new one and go on.
4. Instead of putting `File` descriptor for each image file to `LinkedBlockingQueue`, put there `Integer` objects, where each will correspond to filled subfolder with same name.
5. Inside `RenameScreenShots` take new element from `LinkedBlockingQueue`, consider this element as a subfolder name and process all quietly files within this subfolder.

**UPD-2** The scheme introduced in my `UPD-1` could be more easily implemented using a shared `synchornized` getter of some integer value, which will correspond to the last number of the processed subfolder.

Comment: If LinkedBlockingQueue takes up space in memory then this wouldn't be a good solution as all the files would take up space in the main memory and if there are billions of images then this surely doesn't make sense

Comment: `File` object is just simple descriptor of some file (in a nutshell, consider it like wrapper, which contains just it name and path on the disk). It will not eat a lot of memory.

Comment: Well the linked blocking queue will surely store the file descriptors as references so what good have I done if I am using a billion references there still will be a memory issue moreover the workaround you told of creating subfolders would complicate my job rather than easing it out.

Comment: man I added the LinkedBlockingQueue functionality to the code and I guess the problem is resolved now but I can't find loopholes if any in the code as I am using this functionality for the first time, can you point out some improvements that can be made to the code if any.

Comment: @Coder, hello! I don't know any loopholes related to this solution. Could you please explain more detailed, what do you mean? I will assist you to the best of my ability.

Comment: I want to ask if there can be memory issues because of this solution or not?

Answer (score 2):

maybe you can try file lock.  each file can be a file lock.

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(some_file, "rw");
FileChannel fc = file.getChannel();
FileLock lock = fc.tryLock();
....
lock.release()
```

when you write screanshot to a file such as A.shot, you create the file A.shot, and hold the file lock of A.shot, then write data into it. when the file is finished, release the file lock.

the rename process should try to get the file lock first, if succeed, then do rename work.
if the file lock can not be got (as the write thread have not released the lock), then wait.

hope it's useful.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

If the actions are synchronized, that is they are run serially, then you really should not have two separate threads for it.

Do write and rename sequentially in the same thread and eliminate the need for synchronization.

Comment: I need the 2 threads to access the folder separately and independently that is why I need multithreading

Comment: Why? You have two operations, one has to happen after the other. There is no gain in using separate threads since nothing can be done in parallel. If you're still set on multithreading (even though it's of no use), look into using something like a `java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue`. Thread 1 does what it needs to do and pushes the filename onto the queue. Thread 2 takes from the queue and processes the file. Manual synchronization should always be your last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you have a [Mutex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771347/what-is-mutex-and-semaphore-in-java-what-is-the-main-difference) and based on the Mutex controll the behaviour of the Threads accessing the Folder ??

Comment: Can you point me to an example or give an example of how its used in java and how it can be used in this situation

Comment: The idea is simple, both the thread look for the Monitor status if monitor is available then they'll lock the monitor and complete the process (of accesing folder) and once the job is done release the monitor. but, this also causes other thread to wait

Comment: This [Answser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194227/named-system-mutex-in-java) ??