# Read from already open CMD - java

Tags: java, command-line, cmd

Is there anyway that a java application can read from an already open CMD window. For example, I've opened a cmd, ran "dir" and then decided to run my application, is there any way my application can read the information that's already in the open CMD window without opening another?
Thanks in advance

UPDATE:
My hope was that when one java application was ran, it would check any currently opened CMD windows to ensure that another one of my command-line applications hadn't been ran before it opened it itself.

Comment: Probably not - can you explain why you need that? There may be another way.

Comment: You cannot. But you can run the dir commnad from within java by using a [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and use its outputstream  to read the contents.

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan Thanks for both your responses, I did know about the ability to read from the ProcessBuilder. My hope was that when one java application was ran, it would check any currently opened CMD windows to ensure that another one of my command-line applications hadn't been ran before it opened it itself.

Comment: @John.Smith is the other application still running? In that case you can check the running processes. If not, you can maybe have a file or database that indicates the last run or something like that.

Comment: @assylias the application would check if the other was still running yes, I looked into running processes but as they are both command-line interfaces all that appears in the process list is cmd.exe (hence the above question). I may have to use the file alternative that you suggested thank you.

Comment: @John.Smith If single instance is what you meant, in windows there is a concept of mutex. You can achieve something [similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194227/getting-exclusive-system-wide-lock-in-java) using file locks

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan Apologies but what you just said went straight over my head, what is meant by single instance? As in the file is only able to be ran once at a time?

Comment: @John.Smith Single instance as in, regardless of how many times you try to run an application, there will be just 1 process that actually gets invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just spool the output of the executed command in a file.

For example : do `dir > spool.txt`
and from the java program open the `spool.txt` file with a `FileInputStream`.

To be sure that the content is totally written before reading it,  you could for example :

- use a marker in the written file to indicate it
- check the modification date of the written file (if the modification date doesn't change during a defined period, it may be the signal that the writing is finished)

---

**Update with updated question : checking whether a CMD windows is opened**

> UPDATE: My hope was that when one java application was ran, it would
>   check any currently opened CMD windows to ensure that another one of
>   my command-line applications hadn't been ran before it opened it
>   itself.

You could simply list the running processes of Windows by using the `tasklist.exe` program.
The information is retrieved with one line by process.
Then, check if one of the lines starts with `cmd.exe`.
If it is the case, it means a  `cmd.exe` program is already running.

Here is a sample code ;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class CmdProcessSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean anyCmdProgramOpened = isAnyCmdProgramOpened();
        System.out.println("isOpened = " + anyCmdProgramOpened);
    }
    public static boolean isAnyCmdProgramOpened() {
        Process p;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(System.getenv("windir") + "\\system32\\" + "tasklist.exe");
            String line;
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                if (line.startsWith("cmd.exe")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

The    `C:\windows\system32` is usually in the PATH environment variable.
So, `p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe");` should be enough
but to prevent any side effect or misconfiguration problem, specifying the absolute path is better.

---

**New update with new comment : checking whether the Java application is running**

> I have used this code for a different section but if there is a cmd
>   window running, there is no guarantee that the user has used it to run
>   my program,  package process;

In this case,  if you can install jdk tools on the client machine you could check if is running a Java process using as main class, the main class of your application.
You could use `jps` ([Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jps.html)).

Here is the available options :

> OPTIONS
>
> The jps command supports a number of options that modify the
>   output of the command. These options are subject to change or removal
>   in the future.
>
> -q
>
> Suppress the output of the class name, JAR file name, and arguments passed to the main method, producing only a list of local VM
>   identifiers.
>
> -m
>
> Output the arguments passed to the main method. The output may be null for embedded JVMs.
>
> -l
>
> Output the full package name for the application's main class or the full path name to the application's JAR file.
>
> -v
>
> Output the arguments passed to the JVM.
>
> -V
>
> Output the arguments passed to the JVM through the flags file (the .hotspotrc file or the file specified by the -XX:Flags=
>   argument).
>
> -Joption
>
> Pass option to the java launcher called by jps. For example, -J-Xms48m sets the startup memory to 48 megabytes. It is a common convention for -J to pass options to the underlying VM executing
>   applications written in Java.

`jps -l` command that outputs the full package name for the application's main class or the full path name to the application's JAR file.

Here is a sample code by searching the main class of the application `process.JavaProcessSearch` :

```
package process;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class JavaProcessSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        boolean isProcessRunning = isAJavaProcessWithMainClass("process.JavaProcessSearch");
        System.out.println(isProcessRunning);
    }

    public static boolean isAJavaProcessWithMainClass(String mainClass) {
        Process p;
        try {
             String javaHome = System.getenv("JAVA_HOME");
             p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(javaHome + File.separator + "bin/jps -l");

            String line;
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                if (line.contains(mainClass)) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

If you cannot install jdk tools, you could store "somewhere" on the client machine, the process id of the application when it is started. 
You can retrieve this information with the following method : `ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()`.

When it is not any longer running (stopped or crashed), you could remove this process id information.
When the application ia started, if a process id is retrieved on the client machine, you don't allow the application to start.
For stopped application case, shutdown hook should do the job.
For crashed application case, you could use a deamon thread that checks on a regular basis whether the application is always running by relying on the stored process id.

Comment: Apologies, example was misleading, please see update

Comment: I have used this code for a different section but if there is a cmd window running, there is no guarantee that the user has used it to run my program, for all I know they ran ipconfig at an earlier point and just didn't close the window.

Comment: In this case you have just to check if your program is running with `jps -l`. I have updated with a new code.

Comment: So with your newly provided code, I just have to change the "process.JavaProcessSearch" to "_package name_. _class name_"?

Comment: Also I had an error "Cannot run program 'jps'" I'm assuming this is to do with how the "PATH" is configured meaning I probably won't be able to use this as I won't be able to guarantee that the user has their computer correctly configured with the "PATH"

Comment: Indeed and the program is located in the JAVA_HOME\bin folder. In this case, if `JAVA_HOME` var is specified, just specify it in the path. I updated with it. If you want to ensure some things, you also have some requirements to achieve it.

Comment: Is the JAVA_HOME variable setup automatically or does the user have to do it? If it requires user action, is there a way I can get around that, e.g. specify the path instead of using JAVA_HOME, (I've tried doing this but as there is a space in the directory name it's not liking it)?

Comment: It depends on the machine configuration used. Yes you could specify the absolute path but clearly it is not advised because if the path changes, it will not work any longer.